# preg_match_all for backslash [\] & [u002F]

Tags: php, regex

I have a URL:

```
https:\u002F\u002Fsite.vid.com\u002F93836af7-f465-4d2c-9feb-9d8128827d85\u002F6njx6dp3gi.m3u8?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiSU4iLCJkZXZpY2VfaWQiOiI1NjYxZTY3Zi0yYWE3LTQ1MjUtOGYwYy01ODkwNGQyMjc3ZmYiLCJleHAiOjE2MTA3MjgzNjEsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiV0VCIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MH0.c3Xhi58DnxBhy-_I5yC2XMGSWU3UUkz5YgeVL1buHYc","
```

And I want to match it using preg_match_all. My regex expression is:

```
preg_match_all('/(https:\/\/site\.vid\.com\/.*\",")/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

But I am not able to match special character `\` & `u002F` in above code. I tried using (escaping fuction). But it is not matching. I know it maybe a lame question, but if anyone could help me in matching `\` and `u002F` or in escaping `\` and `u002F` in preg_match_all, that would be helpfull.

Question Edit:

I want to use only `preg_match_all` because I am trying to extract above URL from a html page.

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~https:(?://|(?:\\\\u002F){2})site\.vid\.com(?:/|\\\\u002F)[^"]*~', $string)`, see https://regex101.com/r/OxfJYL/1/ and [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/IUFZa).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Bro! It's working fine. can you please provide me explanation about this expression. I am new! Hope not asking much

Comment: Yes, I added the explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```php
preg_match_all('~https:(?://|(?:\\\\u002F){2})site\.vid\.com(?:/|\\\\u002F)[^"]*~', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OxfJYL/1/). *Details*:

- `https:` - a literal string (if `s` is optional, use `https?:`)
- `(?://|(?:\\u002F){2})`  - a non-capturing group matching either `//` or (`|`) two occurrences of `\u002F`
- `site\.vid\.com` - a literal `site.vid.com` string (the dot is a metacharacter that matches any char but line break chars, so it must be escaped)
- `(?:/|\\u002F)` -  a non-capturing group matching `/` or `\u002F` text
- `[^"]*` - a negated character class matching zero or more chars other than `"`.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/IUFZa):

```php
$re = '~https:(?://|(?:\\\\u002F){2})site\.vid\.com(?:/|\\\\u002F)[^"]*~';
$str = 'https:\\u002F\\u002Fsite.vid.com\\u002F93836af7-f465-4d2c-9feb-9d8128827d85\\u002F6njx6dp3gi.m3u8?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiSU4iLCJkZXZpY2VfaWQiOiI1NjYxZTY3Zi0yYWE3LTQ1MjUtOGYwYy01ODkwNGQyMjc3ZmYiLCJleHAiOjE2MTA3MjgzNjEsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiV0VCIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MH0.c3Xhi58DnxBhy-_I5yC2XMGSWU3UUkz5YgeVL1buHYc","';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches[0]);
// => Array( [0] => https:\u002F\u002Fsite.vid.com\u002F93836af7-f465-4d2c-9feb-9d8128827d85\u002F6njx6dp3gi.m3u8?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiSU4iLCJkZXZpY2VfaWQiOiI1NjYxZTY3Zi0yYWE3LTQ1MjUtOGYwYy01ODkwNGQyMjc3ZmYiLCJleHAiOjE2MTA3MjgzNjEsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiV0VCIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MH0.c3Xhi58DnxBhy-_I5yC2XMGSWU3UUkz5YgeVL1buHYc )
```

Comment: Tysm sir! Getting answer from you! ( 457,304 rep+)  thank you very much